# Yarn Start Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, react-admin, react-scripts

I create react app with create-react-app and install react-admin . when I want to start  development server with yarn start throw an error unhand-led 'error' event and say Command failed with exit code 1 
I search a lot but nothing helped. See the error in the below image [image]

Comment: Did you tried npm?

Comment: Yes same error happen

Comment: In your project root directory run this rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn
and then try to yarn start again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, look carefully at this:

```js
{
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
```

1. `errno: 'ENOENT'` means the file or directory is not found
2. `path: 'cmd'` denotes the executable `cmd` was not found locally or globally while spawning process `cmd` via Node.js
3. Now, I don't want to go into details. Just know that your operating system needs to keep track of some variables which can be accessed globally. One of such variable is called `$PATH`. The executables inside directories mentioned in the `$PATH` can be accessed from anywhere on your system.
4. Here, `'C:\Windows\system32'` is a path where windows keeps some critical executables. `cmd.exe` is one of them. Somehow the path was deleted from the $PATH variable. In order to fix the problem, an easy solution is:

   - Go to `start-menu` -> `search` and type `environment variables` and open it
   - There will be a variable named PATH. Append `C:\Windows\system32` to it and press OK. If you're on Windows 7 or below, add a semi-colon `;` before it
   - Restart your terminal or IDE or code editor and try running the app. See if the error comes again

Comment: tnx alot it solved my problem i don't think problem is in environment variables

Answer (score 3):

## PROBLEM

It seems to install babel changed many nodes, yet it did NOT update the `yarn.lock` and `package.json` files accordingly

---

### SOLUTION

```
yarn info
```

Then run

```
 yarn upgrade
```

Then

```
yarn add yarn
```

Comment: what errors did you get initially?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and tried almost all solution in the net, for 5 hours, I was struggling but at last I ran into this solution it it solved thi issue.

simply try this:
$ npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@5.0.1

this should work.

Answer (score -1):

I've just restarted the terminal and `yarn start'` worked for me.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
I've tried the solutions given in the following posts, but they didn't help.

- [error Command failed with exit code 1. when I try to run yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323656/error-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-i-try-to-run-yarn)
- [How to fix "Received invalid response from npm" when using other registry in .npmrc and .yarnrc](https://dev.to/vkoudela/how-to-fix-received-invalid-response-from-npm-when-using-other-registry-in-npmrc-and-yarnrc-173f),
- [yarn+react: error Command failed with exit code 1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/4009)

Comment: what errors did you get initially?

Answer (score -1):

## I followed the above guidelines and the only following worked for me

`yarn info`
which actually failed
then I run
=> `yarn upgrade`
which took 5 minutes or more to complete
then finally I run
=> `yarn add yarn`
after this, I was able to start my server successfully by running my own script yar

Comment: what errors did you get initially?

Comment: It was the exact same error @Mohammadreza Mahjoob asked up, later I realized it happens quiet commonly

Answer (score -1):

**Here's what worked for me:**

1. Check if your user has administration privileges
2. If not, then log in the PC's admin account
3. Press "Win + R" then
4. Type "control userpasswords2" and press enter
5. In the Users tab select your user and click "Properties"
6. Then, mark the Administrator option and click OK
7. Finally, log off and try again.

Comment: what errors did you get initially?

Comment: The same as the OP. That's why I just posted the answer

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fixed it Yarn **"Failed with errors"** with the following. ([Source](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#step-by-step))

```
> yarn install
> npm install -g yarn
> yarn set version berry
```

Commit your changes:

```
> git status
> git add .
> git commit -m "upgraded yarn"
```

Run Yarn :

```
> yarn -v
3.2.4
> yarn install
```

Comment: what errors did you get initially?