# Yarn:- Exit code:1; Command failed, while trying to create yarn app

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to create a next.js app with tailwindcss, but when I enter the following command:

```
yarn create next-app -e -tailwindcss demo-app-full
```

It always results with an error, viz:-

```
$ yarn create next-app -e -tailwindcss demo-app-full
yarn create v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-next-app@12.0.10" with binaries:
      - create-next-app
'C:\Users\7386-85615SG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-next-app
Arguments: -e -tailwindcss demo-app-full
Directory: C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642\Desktop\HEMANG\Pionauts
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

To bypass this, I have done various steps, which include

```
 1.     yarn upgrade
        yarn add yarn
        yarn info

 2. npm install -g npm@latest
    nvm install node
    npm install -g yarn
```

Tried using the steps given in this solution:- [Yarn Start Command failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611766/yarn-start-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)
but this also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I've had and solved this issue before.

Let's understand why this happens and how to avoid it happening ever again.

**Cause:**
Windows usernames usually contain a space in the username especially if you set it up using the default windows setup prompt which creates your user based on "FirstName LastName".

**Solution(s):**
Now editing your username isn't feasible. You could set your yarn proxy and yarn config to some other location like D:\yarnData but that doesn't look pretty and it is a redundancy to folders already created during the yarn setup.

first run these commands:

```
 yarn cache dir
 yarn global bin
```

It will output to something like:

```
C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6
C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
```

**Solution 1**. Use the user directory shorthand
i.e you can set the directory to say say C:\Users\7386-8561~1 that internally is equesl to C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642 .
How:

1. Open CMD
2. Navigate to `C:\Users` and run the command `dir /x`
   This should output something like this
   `Directory of C:\Users`

   ```
       23-06-2022  00:06    <DIR>                       .
       23-06-2022  00:06    <DIR>                       ..
       21-11-2020  13:33    <DIR>                       Public
       28-06-2022  11:50    <DIR>          SIDDHA~1     Siddharth Shetty
   ```

   Note down the alias next to your user. Here in my case it is `SIDDHA~1`, for you it could be `7386~1`
3. Run commands:

   ```
   yarn config set cache-folder "C:\Users\SIDDHA~1\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache" (without the V6)
   yarn config set prefix "C:\Users\SIDDHA~1\AppData\Local\Yarn" (without the bin)
   ```
4. Reload your shell and run the commands - it should work.

**Solution 2**. Set up a shortcut to point to your user folder.
i.e you can create a mklink that sets say C:\Users\NameSurname to point to => C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642 .
How:

1. Open CMD in Administrator mode (not powershell as the command is cmd only)
2. Create a directory junction (directory hard link) using the [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command:

   ```
   mklink /J "C:\Users\NameSurname" "C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642"
   ```
3. Run commands:

   `yarn config set cache-folder "C:\Users\NameSurname\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache"` (without the V6)

   `yarn config set prefix "C:\Users\NameSurname\AppData\Local\Yarn"` (without the bin)
4. Reload your shell and run the commands it should work.

Comment: Do you also have solutions for MAC users for the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The path here is most probably the cause `C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642` Spaces in folder names show up as issues and are not a good idea, try creating a simple structure like `C:\MyProject` and retry.

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: When you renamed the folder and ran - what is the exact output?