# app works with yarn start but not in simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, cocoapods, yarnpkg

I am using `yarn run ios` to run a react native project in Xcode simulator. This was working perfectly till two weeks ago but it's not working right now. Now, I get errors like these:

```
error: /Users/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Inst/Pods-Inst.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Inst" in project "Inst") (in target 'Inst' from project 'Inst')

** BUILD FAILED **

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I had already tried cleaning cache, removing node modules etc etc but nothing works.

[error Command failed with exit code 1. when I try to run yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323656/error-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-i-try-to-run-yarn)

If I simply do `yarn start`, I think it builds successfully since I can see the flower and all on the terminal. However, when I try using the simulator, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `/ios` folder and the run the following command:

   ```
   pod install && pod update
   ```
2. Then go back to the project folder and run the following command:

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules && npm install
   ```
3. Next, clean the `ios` build folder:

   ```
   rm -rf ios/build
   ```
4. After that, just run as usual:

   ```
   react-native run-ios
   ```