# Yarn / node command "error Command failed with exit code 1." no error

Tags: node.js, error-handling, yarnpkg

I've got a weird issue going on. I have a node service being started with `yarn ...`. The app seems to work fine for some random amount of time before I get hit with a...

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

There is no error logged. My service already has the following two handlers, but they never log anything when the service dies like this.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err: any) => {
    logger.fatal({ err: err }, 'Process failed. Unhandled Rejection');
  });

  process.on('uncaughtException', (list) => {
    logger.fatal({ err: list }, 'unhandledExceptionThrown');
  });
```

I've read some other SO question ([error Command failed with exit code 1. when I try to run yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323656/error-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-i-try-to-run-yarn)) and tried to clear node modules / clean my yarn cache, but so far that has not helped the issue.

Is there something else I can try to track down what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging around, I found something that was able to help move me in the right direction. Im not sure why the handlers above weren't catching the issue, however... when I added `--unhandled-rejections=strict` to my node command to start the service, the app would blow up as expected and actually would output some useful information.