# error An unexpected error occurred: deploy to Vercel

Tags: github, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my App and it won't deploy to Vercel it keeps showing these errors, and this is my first time doing this so I'm pretty new to deployment, I'm specifically trying to deploy the backend folder:

```
[10:04:12.907] Cloning github.com/MHMDHIDR/mhmdhidr-react (Branch: main, Commit: 1dd8e98)
[10:04:13.751] Cloning completed: 843.557ms
[10:04:13.989] Looking up build cache...
[10:04:14.130] Build Cache not found
[10:04:14.170] Running "vercel build"
[10:04:14.809] Vercel CLI 28.2.2
[10:04:14.930] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[10:04:15.558] Installing dependencies...
[10:04:16.021] yarn install v1.22.17
[10:04:16.096] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[10:04:16.100] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[10:04:16.212] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[10:04:17.621] error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/utils-have-names/-/utils-have-names-1.2.3.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
[10:04:17.622] info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/vercel/path0/backend/yarn-error.log".
[10:04:17.622] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[10:04:22.376] Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 1
```

My Github code:

https://github.com/MHMDHIDR/mhmdhidr-react

and I already added vercel.json

Comment: I found my solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323656/error-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-i-try-to-run-yarn Thanks anyways.