# By using Nodejs 18.12.1 and Yarn 3.3.0 I can't create Shopify app using (yarn create @shopify/app)

Tags: reactjs, shopify, yarnpkg

```
hope@hope-Inspiron-N5050:/opt/lampp/htdocs/shopify/$ yarn create @shopify/app
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0032: │ keytar@npm:7.9.0: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ node-addon-api@npm:4.3.0: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ @npmcli/move-file@npm:2.0.1 is deprecated: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 20s 239ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 957ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0007: │ keytar@npm:7.9.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 6s 502ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 28s 116ms


Welcome. Let’s get started by naming your app. You can change it later.
✔ Your app's name? · yarn3
✔ Which template would you like to use? · php
✔ Downloaded template from https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-php#c
li_three
✔ App initialized
  ✔ Liquid parsed
  ✔ Updated package.json
❯ Installing dependencies with yarn
  ✔ Installed dependencies in /
  ✖ Command failed with exit code 1: yarn install
    Usage Error: The nearest package directory (/tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1ae…
    - If /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app isn't intended to be a pro…
    - If /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app is intended to be a projec…
    - Finally, if /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app is fine and you i…
    $ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--check-cache]…
◼ Clean up
◼ Initializing a Git repository...

── external error ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Error coming from `yarn install`

Command failed with exit code 1: yarn install
Usage Error: The nearest package directory
(/tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app/web/frontend) doesn't seem to be part
 of the project declared in /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app.

- If /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app isn't intended to be a project,
remove any yarn.lock and/or package.json file there.
- If /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app is intended to be a project, it
might be that you forgot to list web/frontend in its workspace configuration.
- Finally, if /tmp/abbdef41d78e306ae681b1aec35a1b70/app is fine and you intend
web/frontend to be treated as a completely separate project (not even a
workspace), create an empty yarn.lock file in it.

$ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--check-cache]
[--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
```

I have tried with Yarn version 1.22 it was working fine but in Yarn version 3.3.0 the project is not creating.

Comment: This is best sent to Shopify, via their Github issues. You will likely get zero help from StackOverflow for this.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323656/error-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-i-try-to-run-yarn ? Can you share what system do you use?